# Debug wordpress: How to find out all functions hooked to an action

Tags: php, wordpress

I have read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/how-to-know-what-functions-are-hooked-to-an-action-filter. It seems very simple: `$wp_filters['action_name']` contains the callback functions that are hooked to the action. However, in my case, it seems there are some other hidden functions that can't be found in this way.

For learning purpose, I am working on https://websitedemos.net/blog-02/ this page, which is an Astra theme starter template, to find out how the hero image gets rendered.

It is an Astra custom layout built using Elementor, I am trying to understand how Astra theme calls the callback function for the hero image.

[image]

So far, I've found the action, it is `astra_header_after`in Astra's `header.php` file

```
astra_header_before();
astra_header();  //I I comment out this line, the Nav bar is gone but the hero image remains.
astra_header_after(); // If I comment out this line, the hero image won't show
astra_content_before();
.............
function astra_header_after() {
    do_action( 'astra_header_after' );
}
```

A full text search for `astra_header_after` returns:

[image]

And this is the only line adding callback function to `astra_header_after`. **So it seems to me this `load_markup` method is the only callback function that is hooked to `astra_header_after`.**

Then I go to look at this `load_markup` method, and I can't find the code that will connect to elementor and render the hero image. Actually, even if I comment out every line in this load_markup method, the hero image still gets rendered.

```
public function load_markup() {

        // Get our options.
        $advanced_headers_layout         = Astra_Ext_Advanced_Headers_Loader::astra_advanced_headers_layout_option( 'layout' );
        $advanced_headers_merged         = Astra_Ext_Advanced_Headers_Loader::astra_advanced_headers_layout_option( 'merged' );
        $advanced_header_bg_size         = Astra_Ext_Advanced_Headers_Loader::astra_advanced_headers_design_option( 'bg-size' );
        $advanced_header_parallax_device = Astra_Ext_Advanced_Headers_Loader::astra_advanced_headers_design_option( 'parallax-device' );

        if ( ! self::advanced_header_enabled() || ( is_front_page() && 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! $advanced_headers_merged ) {
            $combined = 'ast-title-bar-wrap';

            // Parallax variable.
            $parallax = ( 'none' !== $advanced_header_parallax_device ) ? '  ast-advanced-headers-parallax' : '';
            // Parallax Device.
            $parallax_device = ( 'none' !== $advanced_header_parallax_device ) ? $advanced_header_parallax_device : '';
            // Parallax speed variable.
            $parallax_speed = apply_filters( 'astra_advanced_header_parallax_speed', 2 );
            // Full Screen vertical align center.
            $vertical_center = ' ast-advanced-headers-vertical-center';
            // Full Screen.
            $full_screen = ( 'full-screen' == $advanced_header_bg_size ) ? ' ast-full-advanced-header' : '';

            // Add advanced header wrapper classes.
            printf(
                '<div class="%1$s" %2$s role="img" %3$s>',
                $combined . $parallax . $full_screen . $vertical_center,
                ( ! empty( $parallax ) ) ? 'data-parallax-speed="' . esc_attr( $parallax_speed ) . '" data-parallax-device="' . esc_attr( $parallax_device ) . '"' : '',
                $this->get_header_background_image_alt_text() // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            );
        }

        if ( 'disable' !== $advanced_headers_layout ) {
            // Add markup.
            astra_get_template( 'advanced-headers/template/' . $advanced_headers_layout . '.php' );
        }

        echo '</div>';

        // Page Header with no content is selected.
        if ( 'disable' != $advanced_headers_layout ) {
            add_filter( 'astra_the_title_enabled', '__return_false' );
        }

    }
```

Now I wonder if there is any other callback function hooked to `astra_header_after`. So I use the code in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/how-to-know-what-functions-are-hooked-to-an-action-filter) to check all the callback functions that are hooked to it. Here is the output:

[image]

There seems to be no other callback function than `load_markup`. So, I am stuck here. How can I investigate further?

Comment: Sometimes, going down the official path just doesn't work how you expect it. If I were you, I'd temporarily hack the [core function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/adae6bc86d44f1a057dd4bbda1a1dd5f3e99cd82/wp-includes/plugin.php#L435), inspect `$hook_name` for your value, and call `debug_print_backtrace()` or similar for your situation. If _that_ doesn't get what you expect, then the code isn't being called as part of a `do_action`.

Comment: Use Query Monitor plugin.  You can see all of that quite easily.